# Using initializing instance as a parameter in other's class instance initialization

Tags: ruby

I have this classes (just a simplified example, not real ones)

```
class Shop

  attr_accessor :name, :products

  def initialize(name, products_names=%w(apple orange apple cucumber fennel))
    self.name = name
    self.products = products_names.map {|name| Product.new(self, name)}
  end

end 

class Product

  attr_accessor :shop, :name

  def initialize(shop, name)
    self.shop = shop
    self.name = name
  end

  def existing_products_count # problem_comes_here
    shop.products #i need to process all products initialized for current shop
      .select{|p| p.name==name}.size
  end

  def uniq_code
    "#{name}_#{existing_products_count+1}"
  end

end
```

And here is two questions:

1. Is this a good approach to pass `self` for `Product` instance initialization

and

2. How can i solve my case to process all already existing shop products for new product initialization

Thank you

#### UPDATE

all i invented for now is (at least it works like i need)

```
class Shop

  attr_accessor :name, :products

  def initialize(name, products_names=%w(apple orange apple cucumber fennel))
    Product.class_variable_set(:@@all, []) # << added
    self.name = name
    self.products = products_names.map {|name| Product.new(self, name)}
  end

end 

class Product

  attr_accessor :shop, :name

  def self.all # << added
    @@all
  end

  def initialize(shop, name)
    self.shop = shop
    self.name = name
    self.class.all << self # << added
  end

  def existing_products_count # problem goes away here
    self.class.all.products  # << changed
      .select{|p| p.name==name}.size
  end

  def uniq_code
    "#{name}_#{existing_products_count+1}"
  end

end
```

but i feel bad about this kind of solution (i don't know why) and will be appreciate for better one

Comment: 1. Not good, not bad, just an option (used by many). 2. I do not understand. What is `generate_uniq_code`? It's always best for examples to be self-contained so they can be used in testing possible solutions (with example input and desired output).

Comment: It's just an option. Code School uses it in some of their courses on Ruby if that makes you feel any better :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, in general - i agree, but i suggest my current real code too complicated to share it without simplification (for better readablility)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, i have updated my question to replace abstract `generate_uniq_code`. But it is not the attention point, just some method where all `shop.products` have to be processed what i am asking for

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but here is one interpretation. Note how I've changed the method `Product#uniq_code`.

```
class Shop
  attr_accessor :name, :products    
  def initialize(name, products_names=%w(apple orange apple cucumber fennel))
    self.name = name
    self.products = products_names.map {|name| Product.new(self, name)}
  end    
end 

class Product    
  attr_accessor :shop, :name    
  def initialize(shop, name)
    self.shop = shop
    self.name = name
  end

  def uniq_code # problem_comes_here
    puts "buy #{self.name} #{self.shop.name}"
  end
end
```

Now let's have an example:

```
at_store = Shop.new("in store", ["bulldozer", "Ducati"])
online   = Shop.new("online", ["can opener", "Makita router"])
arr = [at_store, online]
```

We can do this:

```
arr.flat_map { |s| s.products }.each { |p| p.send(:uniq_code) }
  # buy bulldozer in store
  # buy Ducati in store
  # buy can opener online
  # buy Makita router online
```

Is this roughly what you were looking for?

Edit: to save the product instances for a given shop instance:

```
product_instances = at_store.products
  #=> [#<Product:0x007f93f984f938
  #      @shop=#<Shop:0x007f93f984f988 @name="in_store",
  #      @products=[...]>, @name="bulldozer">,
  #    #<Product:0x007f93f984f910
  #      @shop=#<Shop:0x007f93f984f988 @name="in_store",
  #      @products=[...]>, @name="Ducati">]
```

for use later:

```
product_instances.each { |p| p.uniq_code }
  # buy bulldozer in_store
  # buy Ducati in_store
```

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot you pay attention to my question, i remember your excellent answer to one of my previous questions! but now it is not the case to modify `uniq_code` method. i just need to collect somehow all product instances for current shop to process them somehow later inside other product instance method

Comment: we are somewhere near =) I need `def product_instances; at_store.products; end` for my `Product` class but here we have (undefined) `at_store` method which i can't figure how to build (at_store would contain same products for any next new product). maybe i need to collect and "memoize" somehow Product.all (and use self.class.all instead of shop.products) but i do not like singleton methods in case it is not definitely necessary

Comment: I'll get back to this later, but other readers are encouraged to offer advice.